# Help me pick a less Trope-centric title for my question?

Tags: discussion

Help me pick a less Troper-centric for my question?

[When was the first instance of Grimmification?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131540/when-was-the-first-instance-of-grimmification)

Initially, it was:

**When was the first darker remake of a fairy tale?**

---

However, that title got me these comments, informing me on what's wrong with my title:

> The original versions of fairy tales were at least as dark as any modern remake. Does that count as an answer? – @DJClayworth
>
> You may be unaware that pretty much all of the original versions of fairy tales are dramatically darker than their 20th century retellings. @Valorum

And my criteria for selecting an answer is as follows:

> @Armadillo - I would accept any instance of a fairy tale being made darker, as long as it was historically preceded by a lighter version, that the darker's author would have known about, and (most likely) made a conscious choice to remake in darker fashion.

---

So, can you guys help me pick a better title?

Comment: Sorry, but what does "pick a less Troper-centric" mean?

Comment: The problem isn't the title. The problem is the underlying premise. The best title in the world won't fix that.

Comment: @Valorum - So, what do you think is the underlying premise, and what's wrong with it?

Comment: I think it's more important for everyone else to understand what **your** intended premise is... you're the one asking the question.

Comment: @Malandy - Most of the classic fairy tales have been remade so many times, it's almost impossible to know which versions are knockoffs and which versions are genuinely inspired by the original tales. The original tales themselves are often retellings of earlier stories that are lighter/darker; The Little Mermaid is a perfect case in point with no less than half a dozen film adaptations and at least as many *retellings* before the Disney version; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Mermaid

Comment: @Valorum - Could you make that an answer? 'Cause that seems sufficient refutation of one of my primary assumptions to kill this question. And I don't want to leave this question unanswered...

Comment: @Malandy - I would, but I've had far too much to drink and more than my fair share of [people yelling at me](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/reopening-duplicated-question-start-creating-rules-for-tagging-a-question) this week. If it's still unanswered in the AM, I'll have a think about writing something up for this.

Comment: What would be more valid, in my opinion, is a question asking about the historic *trend* of fairy tales from darker to lighter then darker again. Surely there's literary and media studies that can answer this, especially in a socio-cultural context. However... I doubt it'd go over any better, here.